# NSIS ANTI EMULATOR

Tags: nsis

I'm trying to make a anti emulator
allocating a big memory region and force the kernel to commit the pages to physical ram by filling the memory with values because the emulator can't allocate too much memory
But I don't know how to fill the memory with values of that region
 this is what I made so far

System::Call "kernel32::LocalAlloc(i 0, i 143978374) p .r0" ; allocate 143 978 374 bytes and write pointer in $0

;I need to fill the  memory with values here

System::Call "kernel32::LocalFree(p r0)"

Comment: I assume writing one byte to each page is enough for your needs?

Comment: How Can I do that?

Comment: It is enough. One byte per page but I don't know how I do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `LocalAlloc` with the `LMEM_ZEROINIT` flag Windows might write to the buffer for you. Technically speaking, this might be a implementation detail and in theory a future system could support such a feature in hardware. Your emulation thing, whatever that is, might ignore it as well.

You can write to memory with the system plug-in struct syntax:

```
!define PAGESIZE 4096
!define BLOBSIZE 143978374

!include Util.nsh
!ifndef IntPtrOp ; NSIS 2 compatibility
!define IntPtrOp IntOp
!endif
!ifndef IntPtrCmpU
!define IntCmpU
!endif

System::Alloc ${BLOBSIZE} ; This calls GlobalAlloc(GPTR, ...)
Pop $0
${IntPtrCmpU} $0 0 done "" "" ; Failure to allocate memory?
StrCpy $1 $0 ; Start
${IntPtrOp} $2 $1 + ${BLOBSIZE} ; End
loop:
    System::Call '*$1(&i1 42)' ; Set the first byte in the page to 42
    ${IntPtrOp} $1 $1 + ${PAGESIZE}
    ${IntPtrCmpU} $1 $2 "" loop ""
System::Free $0
done:
```

The System plug-in is not super fast so a large memory block will take a while to fill.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But how I write more than just to commit the pages , somehow the emulator gets past it otherwise.

Comment: You can change &i1 to &i8 to write 64-bits, or you can do *$1(&i8 42,&i8 42,&i8 42,&i8 42,&i8 42) etc.

Comment: Oh , but how can I lower the amount of memory and set all bytes to a value instead of commiting pages?

Comment: Change to *$1(&i8 666) and change PAGESIZE in my code to 8 but that is going to be slow.

Comment: Hello I have tried but seems like this emulator is strong and it filters the code

Comment: I don't understand why you are calling it a emulator. Anyway, the code you posted does not allocate a lot of memory so there is no way this allocate and write plan is going to do anything. You might have more luck trying to prevent mapping of the section somehow.

Comment: Can you help me with the mapping please :D

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to stop NSIS code that is in your installer?

Comment: I'm trying to hide that pastebin code being detected by a emulator ( anti emulator)

Comment: To make it undetectable